# MySQL Return Rows With Zero Count

Tags: mysql

**Table layouts**

reject_data

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| reject_id | reject_location | reject_equipment | reject_time   |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 1         | 7               | 6                | 1326795921000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 2         | 7               | 1                | 1326796641000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 3         | 7               | 6                | 1326799521000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 4         | 6               | 5                | 1326800781000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 5         | 7               | 3                | 1326802281000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 6         | 7               | 4                | 1326802941000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 7         | 7               | 1                | 1326814161000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
| 8         | 6               | 2                | 1328026700000 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
```

equipment

```
+--------------+------------------+
| equipment_id | equipment_string |
+--------------+------------------+
| 1            | Microdoser       |
+--------------+------------------+
| 2            | Monoblock        |
+--------------+------------------+
| 3            | Valve Magnet     |
+--------------+------------------+
| 4            | Checkweigher     |
+--------------+------------------+
| 5            | Microleak        |
+--------------+------------------+
| 6            | Capper           |
+--------------+------------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT equipment_string AS eqpt, COUNT(reject_id) AS cnt
FROM reject_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN equipment ON (reject_equipment = equipment_id) 
WHERE reject_location IN (1,2,7) AND equipment_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) AND reject_time BETWEEN 1329479810000 AND 1329483410000
GROUP BY equipment_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

**Question**

How do I alter my query so that it also returns equipment that have zero counts? Really stuck :(

Thank you for any help.

*Note: Dynamic variable populates the IN normally.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause does the filtering *after* the `JOIN`, so it will filter out any records where the `JOIN` failed (since `reject_location IN (1,2,7)` won't be true for those). You need to move those restrictions to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT equipment_string AS eqpt, COUNT(reject_id) AS cnt
FROM reject_data
RIGHT OUTER JOIN equipment
       ON reject_equipment = equipment_id
      AND reject_location IN (1,2,7)
      AND reject_time BETWEEN 1329479810000 AND 1329483410000
WHERE equipment_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY equipment_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

In this case, another approach, which you might find more clear, is to use a subquery rather than a join:

```
SELECT equipment_string AS eqpt,
       ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM reject_data
          WHERE reject_equipment = equipment_id
            AND reject_location IN (1,2,7)
            AND reject_time BETWEEN 1329479810000 AND 1329483410000
       ) AS cnt
  FROM equipment
 WHERE equipment_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: when i understand the OP correctly, those filters are desired behaviour.

Comment: @Kaii: Sorry, but you *didn't* understand the OP correctly. He/she wants to "also return[] equipment that have zero counts".

Comment: yes, return all rows from equipment, even when there are no countable rejects in table `reject_data`..

Comment: @Kaii: Yes, so those filters *aren't* desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    e.equipment_string AS eqpt, 
    COUNT(reject_id) AS cnt

FROM equipment AS e

LEFT JOIN reject_data AS rd
    ON rd.reject_equipment = e.equipment_id
    AND rd.reject_location IN (1,2,7)
    AND rd.reject_time BETWEEN 1329479810000 AND 1329483410000

WHERE e.equipment_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)

GROUP BY e.equipment_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

By limiting the join criteria you decrease the amount of rows MySQL needs to retrieve

Comment: -1, sorry: your first query is equivalent to the OP's query, and will have the same problem.

Comment: I preferred the second query anyhow - have removed the first